# Not able to use JQuery in Chrome Extensions

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome Extension in which I have a background.js and I am trying to use JQuery in it.

Getting following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

My manifest File code part

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["script.js", "jquery.js","front.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
```

I am not able to get any clue of using JQuery functions in this extension. Please let me know if you need more justification.

Edit#1: Manifest File

```
{
  "name": "Tool",
  "description": "Extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "5.0.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage"
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "icons":{"16": "images/F_icon_16x16.png",
           "48": "images/F_icon_48x48.png",
          "128": "images/F_icon_128x128.png"},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js", "front.js"]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' ; object-src 'self'",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Tool",
      "default_icon": "images/F_icon.png"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this part:

```
"js": ["script.js", "jquery.js","front.js"]
```

to this:

```
"js": ["jquery.js","script.js","front.js"]
```

The order of that line is the order the files are included. so you need first the jquery.js to define the $ (for jquery) and then the other scripts with your scripting...

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena And if you delete this line then??? `"web_accessible_resources": ["https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"],`

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena Can you post your whole manifest then? Or what version are you using???

Comment: check Edit#1: Manifest File

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena Seen, can you confirm that the jquery file is loaded in the browser???

Comment: how do i confirm, that file is in my root folder. If that wasn't,  i will not be able to load my extension in browser.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena If you're using chrome, press F12 and then look through the elements or the Resources and find it there....

Comment: Thanks Marc, it is working now, i just downloaded the latest version of jquery and applied all the methods you suggested.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena, no problem. Glad i could help you out